# Time complexity of javascript Array.prototype.filter()?

Tags: javascript

What is the big O of `Array.protoype.filter`?

I have looked at the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) but haven't been able to work it out.

Comment: ummm O(n)? one would think it operates on every item.

Comment: Algorithmic Complexity: O(N)

Answer (score 15):

O(N)

Example:

```js
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => isBig(word));

function isBig(word){
   console.log("called");
 return word.length > 6;
}
```

Output:

> "called"
>   "called"
>   "called"
>   "called"
>   "called"
>   "called"
>   Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]

Comment: This is actualy insane considering its only one line of code and you can iterate through big arrays in linear time.

Comment: Not sure what's so insane about it. It's one line because of abstraction, and O(n) is linear time...